# can find the text position on base64 encode image

Tags: javascript

**my question is about to Get the image Text Position**

> It can will be possible to get any some text on image like click to
>   find the position on this text in x and y coordinate. i don't know how
>   , resolve the this code . please help me .

Comment: please help me on this

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: can you provide some demo code . because i have some random search code .  function FindPosition(oElement)
{
  if(typeof( oElement.offsetParent ) != "undefined")
  {
    for(var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent)
    {
      posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
      posY += oElement.offsetTop;
    }
      return [ posX, posY ];
    }
    else
    {
      return [ oElement.x, oElement.y ];
    }
}

Comment: thanks for the replay reza saadati

Answer (score 0):

You can get the style of your element with `getComputedStyle()`.

Just a simple example:

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let txt = document.getElementById('txt');
let style = window.getComputedStyle(txt);
btn.addEventListener('click', () => alert(`Left: ${style.paddingLeft}\nTop: ${style.paddingTop}`));
```

```css
li {
  background:
    url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7)
    no-repeat
    left center;
    padding-left: 300px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: skyblue
}
```

```html
<li id="txt">hello</li>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95efdy7h/)

Comment: Thanks for replay

Comment: I am getting the following error:                                                   Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Comment: @NiteshLad there must be something wrong with your parameter. If it is `txt` like in my example, then the ID of your element needs to be `txt` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the replay , i use above same code in my local pc on xampp  and getting error .